# how to svn diff the next revision to the last and the third revision from the end?

Tags: svn, command-line-interface

Say, I'm at r10(latest) in a svn repo, I already got an alias command to view the difference between r9 and r10 with this:

```
svn diff -r PREV | less
```

but now, I usually want to view the difference between r8 and r9, I know I can use `svn diff -c 8:9 | less`, but the revision number is big and I always have to use `svn log` to list the commit history and pick the revision numbers and then type the exact big revision numbers inside command of `svn diff`.

Is there any solution that I can simply view the difference between r8 and r9 like the previous alias and I can make into the shell config, for example, like

```
svn diff -r PREV-2:PRV-1 | less
```

if it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

1. Diff for any (single?) commit in comparison to previous is just `-c` option. I.e, if r10 is last commit in repo, you can `svn diff -c HEAD`, diff for 8:9 will be ``svn diff -c 9` etc.
2. No, you haven't any names (except mentioned in helps)

> ```
> NUMBER       revision number
> '{' DATE '}' revision at start of the date
> 'HEAD'       latest in repository
> 'BASE'       base rev of item's working copy
> 'COMMITTED'  last commit at or before BASE
> 'PREV'       revision just before COMMITTED
> ```

in pure SVN, but can have shorthands for far-parents with any (reasonable) remoteness in Mercurial (and, obviously, hgsubvesion) with cloned into HG Subversion's repo, using revsets, namely "x^n"

```
"x^n"
  The nth parent of x, n == 0, 1, or 2. For n == 0, x; for n == 1, the
  first parent of each changeset in x; for n == 2, the second parent of
  changeset in x.
```

Comment: But I still need a revision number. Is there any solution that I don't have to type any number?